# Alert selected ID from local storage (response from MySQL)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

On server-side - get_notes.php

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result_1)) {
$rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

The output is -

> [{"ID":"1000043","text":"Test "},{"ID":"1000037","text":"Here we go AGAIN!!"}]

JSON loaded by the following script -

```
$('#button').click(function(){
var url="get_notes.php";
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(json));
```

On the client-side index.html *should load JSON array from LocalStorage* (Earlier "we" saved JSON from MySQL response in localstorage) and show to user all notes. After user can choose notes on index.html and *app should alert* to him the ID of note, which he selected.

Function, which shows us an array from LocalStorage:

```
 var array_list = localStorage.getItem("items");
 alert(array_list);
```

**How to alert the ID on the selected note?**

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: When I try to alert selected ID (object) I got - undefined

Comment: `array_list` still needs to be parsed after being retrieved from `localStorage`

Comment: I use - var array_list = localStorage.getItem("items");
     obj = JSON.parse(array_list);
     alert(obj.ID);
But it does not work. The app returns - undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to put the value in console.log()? There is an encoded array of objects in the JSON string. You should get item first.

```
// Moved from comments below:
var list_json = localStorage.getItem('items');
var list = JSON.parse(list_json) || [];
var index, item;
for (index in list) {
  item = list[index];
  alert(item.ID);
}
```

Comment: I work with PhoneGap. 
var array_list = localStorage.getItem("items");
     var list = localStorage.getItem('items',JSON.stringify(list));
     obj = JSON.parse(list);
     alert(obj);
Now I got - [object Object]

Comment: You have two items: {"ID":"1000043","text":"Test "} and {"ID":"1000037","text":"Here we go AGAIN!!"}

Comment: Yes, you are right. Two items - [object Object],[object Object].
If I do like that - alert(obj.ID) - I got undefined

Comment: So what do you want? You can iterate this array and do some magic with an object items. I.e. alert(item.ID);

Comment: If I press on first note, it should alert me the ID - "1000037", but I recieve - undefined.  
P.S: alert(obj.ID);

Comment: var list_json = localStorage.getItem('items'); var list = JSON.parse(list_json) || []; var index, item; for (index in list) { item = list[index]; alert(item.ID); }

Comment: Now I got the needed result. Thanks!